# open-vm-tools doesn't resize display

Tags: vmware, vmware-tools

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 in VMware Workstation 12 Player on Windows 7. Since VMware has stopped updating VMware Tools or something, I have to use open-vm-tools. Unfortunately, it doesn't resize the display. My installation is something of a mess because I've been toying around with the GitHub release, had some problems removing VMware Tools resulting in a partial install, and installed from source code meaning I can't likewise uninstall.

How can I get open-vm-tools to work and properly resize the display?

Comment: Use KVM + spice - native support ;)

Comment: Was this [article](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525) not useful?

Answer (score 13):

You need to install `open-vm-tools-desktop`, just `open-vm-tools` is for console only VMs.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: That's the answer. Wish I could find this easier.